# heroku run bash is not working

Tags: macos, heroku

Why is **heroku run bash** not working?

$ **heroku login**

```
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: xx@yy.zz
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Logged in as xx@yy.zz
```

$ **heroku run bash**

```
 ▸    No app specified.
 ▸    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP
```

$ **heroku run --app bash**

```
 ▸    Usage: heroku run COMMAND
 ▸    
 ▸    Example: heroku run bash
```

$ **heroku run "ls /usr/bin/"**

```
 ▸    No app specified.
 ▸    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP
```

$ **heroku run --app "ls /usr/bin/"**

```
 ▸    Usage: heroku run COMMAND
 ▸    
 ▸    Example: heroku run bash
```

$ **heroku version**

```
heroku-toolbelt/3.42.22 (universal.x86_64-darwin15) ruby/2.0.0
heroku-cli/4.27.11-7569c5d (amd64-darwin) go1.5.2
=== Installed Plugins
heroku-apps@1.1.0
heroku-cli-addons@0.1.1
heroku-fork@4.0.0
heroku-git@2.4.4
heroku-local@4.1.5
heroku-run@2.9.2
heroku-spaces@2.0.9
heroku-status@1.2.4
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error message indicates, you need to specify which heroku app you want to run commands on. (If you're in a git repository with a remote pointing to heroku, it will use that one by default; that's what it means by "from an app folder".)

`$ heroku apps`

will give you a list.

`$ heroku run --app INSERT_APP_NAME_HERE bash`

will run `bash` on that app.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of not specifying the app you want to use. Try this

```
$heroku app
example
$heroku run bash --app examp
```

Answer (score 0):

need to manually specify the name of the image with the run
command like:

```
heroku run bash --type worker -a app_name
```